# Guardar Ids en campo hidden usando typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, autocompletar

tengo el siguiente inconveniente:
Estoy tratando de mostrar en un formulario los establecimientos con campos de **autocompletar múltiples** (es decir en el formulario se van agregando autocompletar según el usuario desee agregar Establecimientos al formulario), la parte de mostar y autocompletar los campos mostrando el nombre del establecimiento (return item) me funciona bien, pero cuando quiero **guardar los ids** correspondientes en un **campo oculto input hidden**, sólo obtengo el último ingresado, cuando necesito todos en el array escuela_id[].
Código:
html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Establecimiento Educativo:</label>
    <input class="form-control typeahead twitter-typeahead" data-provide="typeahead" placeholder="Ingrese el Nº o nombre..." type="text" name="escuela[]">   
    <input type="hidden" name="escuela_id[]" id="escuela_id" value="">                  
  </div>
```

y el script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
var typeaheadSettings = {

    source: function (query, process) {
        return $.get("{{ route('autocomplete') }}", { query: query }, function (data) {
            var objects = [];
            map = {};
            $.each(data, function(i, object) {
                map[object.name] = object;
                objects.push(object.name);
            });
            process(objects);

        });
    },
    updater: function(item) {

        // $('input[name=escuela_id]').val(map[item].id);
        document.getElementById("escuela_id").value=map[item].id;

        return item;

    }
};

$('.typeahead').typeahead(typeaheadSettings); /* init first input */

$('#btn-agrega-escuela').click(function(){
var newRow = $('<div class="form-group padding-abajo-1" id="dv"><label>Establecimiento Educativo:</label><input class="form-control typeahead twitter-typeahead" data-provide="typeahead" placeholder="Ingrese el Nº o nombre..." type="text" name="escuela[]"><input type="hidden" name="escuela_id[]" id="escuela_id" ><br><div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><label for="cant">Número de Asistentes:</label><input type="number" class="form-control" id="cant" name="cant" value="{{ old('cant') }}"></div><div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><label for="cant">Cursos:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="cursos" name="cursos" value="{{ old('cursos') }}"></div>');
newRow.insertBefore('#btn-agrega-escuela');
$('.typeahead').trigger('added');

});

$('.typeahead').on('added',function(){
    $('.typeahead').typeahead(typeaheadSettings);
});});
```

si muestro el array de id ingresando 2 establecimientos me devuelve sólo el id del último ingresado:

```
array:2 [▼  0 => "2" 1 => null]
```

Soy nueva en el tema, agradezco si me pueden ayudar necesito guardar TODOS los Id de los establecimientos en el campo input hidden, o como poder pasarlo y guardarlo. (mostrar el nombre del establecimiento, pero para trabajar después necesito los id !!!) Gracias
(usando Laravel/php, bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js,  )

Comment: El problema es que estas usando el mismo `id` para todos los inputs y se supone que tiene que ser unico.  En lugar de eso utiliza clases.

Comment: Gracias por comentar! No entiendo bien a qué te referís? podrías ampliar tu explicación o detallarla, me sería de gran ayuda!

Comment: Cada vez que presionas el boton `agrega-escuela` insertas un input con `id="escuela_id"` pero ese HTML es invalido porque el `id` debe de ser unico en todo el DOM.

Comment: Gracias @alanfcm Perdón que siga molestando, es que no logro solucionarlo! Soy nueva en esto! Si yo saco el id del input hidden y le agrego `class="hiddenId"` ya no me da valores null pero me asigna a TODO el array `escuela_id[]` el valor de ID del último campo ingresado, sabes como debería hacer la asignación o si hay alguna manera de resetearlo cuando se presiona `btn-agrega-escuela` o cuando se llama a la función typeahead??? Gracias de nuevo!